# How to know if a device is in between a location?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

I need to create an android app to detect if someone is around a place. This place has an irregular shape. So basically, if this person is in the place, the app must display a google maps location; if not, open a dialog with some kind of message.

Is there any tutorial that can help me with this?

BTW, very newbie developing for android and using APIs.

**Aditional info:**
I'm planning to do an internal map of a mall (including parking lot, coffee place, etc). But I want the app work only if the user is inside the mall.

**Comments about this:**
Someone told me something about we can use shapes while working with Google Maps API. Can't resolve how to.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: From where would get the two point?

Comment: Example: Think about a square. The area of the shape is where the user must be in order to use the app (applicability: shopping mall, campus, airport, and so on). After that, inside the shape, will be some other locations (ie office, coffee place...) so, the user will have a kind of internal map of the main place.

Comment: Yes I got that I am asking how you planning to fetch the coordinates of the mall(for say). if you surpass this then rest of them is easy I guess

Comment: Yes, I hope so. I have the coordinates of the place and I'm planning to create a polygon.